# How to Make Custom HashPassword function in Feathersjs Authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, feathersjs

I notice in feathersjs documentation

> hashPassword This hook is used to hash plain text passwords before
>   they are saved to the database. It uses the bcrypt algorithm by
>   default but can be customized by passing your own options.hash
>   function.

How do I apply this custom function in feathers js hook, hashPassword hook?

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

const {
  hashPassword, protect
} = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;


module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    create: [ hashPassword() ],
    update: [ hashPassword(),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    patch: [ hashPassword(),  authenticate('jwt') ],
    remove: [ authenticate('jwt') ]
  },

  after: {
    all: [ 
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect('password')
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Does anyone have the answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to work, at least with the current version 1.2.9 of @feathersjs/authentication-local.

In verifier.js, you'll see:

```
 // stuff omitted
_comparePassword (entity, password) {

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function (error, result) {
        // Handle 500 server error.
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }

        if (!result) {
          debug('Password incorrect');
          return reject(false); // eslint-disable-line
        }

        debug('Password correct');
        return resolve(entity);
      });
    });
  }
```

So the default verifier always uses hardcoded bcrypt.compare and not any provided hash function.

The only solution I found was to extend the Verifier and override _comparePassword.
Then: `app.configure(local({ Verifier: MyCustomVerifier }));` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object to `hashPassword` which they call as `options`. Options can have two fields, `passwordField` and `hash`.

```
...    
create: [ hashPassword({passwordField: 'password', hash: hasherFunc}) ]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
//in your hook
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports = (options = {}) => {
  return async (context) => {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const pass = context.data.password;

    const hashed = await bcrypt.hash(pass, salt);

    context.data.password = hashed
  }
}
```

Then you have to remove the other hash function in `/services/users`

Answer (score -1):

Use the library of feathers itself. It's the easiest and most reliable one for now.

```
const hash = require("@feathersjs/authentication-local/lib/utils/hash");

await hash(req.body.password).then(result => { // Do anything });
```